# Find K max values from a N List

Tags: java

I got requirements-
1. Have random values in a List/Array and I need to find 3 max values .
2. I have a pool of values and each time this pool is getting updated may be in every 5 seconds, Now every time after the update , I need to find the 3 max Values from the list pool.

> I thought of using Math.max thrice on the list but I dont think it as
>   a very optimized approach.
>   **> Won't any sorting mechanism be costly as I am bothered about only top
>   3 Max Values , why to sort all these**

Please suggest the best way to do it in JAVA

Comment: On update, are values replaced and removed, or only added?

Comment: You have to understand that "costly" is a relative term. As a programmer you're always trading off various costs. The cost of sorting is O(n log n). That means that even for very large collections, the cost of sorting the list does not grow much faster than simply iterating through the list. Some quick testing reveals that the largest array I can make on my laptop has size roughly 2^27 and the largest that I can sort in five seconds with `Arrays.sort(int[] nums)` is 2^24 (16.7 million entries). If you're picking the top 3 from a pool of less than a million, just sort it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Sort the list, get the 3 max values. If you don't want the expense of the sort, iterate and maintain the n largest values.
2. Maintain the pool is a sorted collection.

Update: FYI Guava has an Ordering class with a `greatestOf` method to get the n max elements in a collection. You might want to check out the implementation.

[Ordering.greatestOf](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.2/javadoc/index.html)

Comment: If the List is super long , then or is there any other way to do it

Comment: Updated the question for sorting scenario

Comment: @bunta use a DoublyLinkedList or just use reverse ordering and the top 3 are the first 3 or the last 3 from the tail.

Comment: You can do it in *O* (*n*) instead of *O* (*n* log *n*).

Comment: For item 1, if you are just given a List you could simply iterate the list and maintain the three max values. This would be more efficient than actually sorting. You could also iterate the List placing all the elements in a sorted collection (like a Tree) then get the 3 max. This is slightly less efficient than just iterating and getting the 3 max.

Comment: checked the API of greatestOf and found its internally using quicksort and If I am allowed to use any sorting technique, definately I will go for this option

Answer (score 3):

Traverse the list once, keeping an ordered array of three largest elements seen so far. This is trivial to update whenever you see a new element, and instantly gives you the answer you're looking for.

Comment: from the question phrasing it seems that he doesn't know what was added or how many.

Comment: missed a verb there, edited. Anyway, this is better since its O(n) and simple and any time the list is changed just re-traverse.

Answer (score 1):

A [priority queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) should be the data structure you need in this case.

Answer (score 1):

First, it would be wise to never say again, "I dont think it as a very optimized approach." You will not know which part of your code is slowing you down until you put a profiler on it.

Second, the easiest way to do what you're trying to do -- and what will be most clear to someone later if they are trying to see what your code does -- is to use `Collections.sort()` and pick off the last three elements. Then anyone who sees the code will know, "oh, this code takes the three largest elements." There is so much value in clear code that it will likely outweigh any optimization that you might have done. It will also keep you from writing bugs, like giving a natural meaning to what happens when someone puts the same number into the list twice, or giving a useful error message when there are only two elements in the list.

Third, if you really get data which is so large that O(n log n) operations is too slow, you should rewrite the data structure which holds the data in the first place -- `java.util.NavigableSet` for example offers a `.descendingIterator()` method which you can probe for its first three elements, those would be the three maximum numbers. If you really want, a Heap data structure can be used, and you can pull off the top 3 elements with something like one comparison, at the cost of making adding an O(log n) procedure.